# Set value for the primay key with strategy set to NONE

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have an Entity class that looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Entities;

/** @Entity @Table(name="User") */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="string", length=12)
     */
    private $no;
```

Based on Doctrine 2 Identifier Generation Strategy section:

> NONE: Tells Doctrine that the
>   identifiers are assigned (and thus
>   generated) by your code. The
>   assignment must take place before a
>   new entity is passed to
>   EntityManager#persist. NONE is the
>   same as leaving off the
>   @GeneratedValue entirely.

That means, I need a way so that I can set the value before calling persist.

Calling `./doctrine orm:generate-entities` wouldn't generate a setter function, do I have to write it manually in the class?

```
/**
 * Set no
 *
 * @param string $no
 */
public function setNo($no)
{
    $this->no = $no;
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "correct" way to do this. the Generate-entities command is just a helper. Nothing that you HAVE to use. You can do as you please.

The only requirement with the assigned strategy is, that the id field has to be non-null when $em->persist() is called.

For example in the case of an assigned ID it makes sense to make it a required parameter in the constructor:

```
class User
{
    private $no;
    public function __construct($no)
    {
        $this->no = $no;
    }
}
```