# Symfony2, manually assign table id value

Tags: symfony

I'm working with symfony2, I have a table and I want to manually assign the id.

In the documentation of doctrine I've found this:

Identifier Generation Strategies

```
"NONE: Tells Doctrine that the identifiers are assigned (and thus generated) 
 by your code. The assignment must take place before a new entity is passed to 
 EntityManager#persist. 
 NONE is the same as leaving off the @GeneratedValue entirely."
```

Pay attention to this: "the assignment must take place before a new entity is passed to En.."

How do I achieve that?

I'm doing this:

```
$empleado->setId("989865446");
```

but it says:

```
Entity of type Entity\Empleado is missing an assigned ID. The identifier 
generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before 
EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated 
identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.
```

EDIT:

```
 /**
 * @var integer $id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;
```

and

```
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code surrounding `$empleado->setId()`?

Comment: How did you implement `setId()` ?

Comment: And needless to say (but I'll say it anyways) make sure your id property is called id.

Comment: I edited the post, so there is the code. Hope you help me.

Comment: Do you use some third party bundles? Maybe one of these calls `persist`. Or some service?

Comment: I'm just using doctrine, and no, there are not more third party bundles. What I really want to know is what does it mean "The assignment must take place before a new entity is passed to 
 EntityManager#persist." because that's how I would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is correct, so the error must have to do with how you're constructing the object and when persist() is called.

There's a similar question here:
[Set value for the primay key with strategy set to NONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291120/set-value-for-the-primay-key-with-strategy-set-to-none)

Are you running the latest versions of Symfony 2/Doctrine 2?

Try making it a required constructor parameter as suggested in the answer above - that should make it impossible for persist() to be called before setting the ID. The error message means just what it says - you have to assign the ID first, *only then* call persist.

You are creating the object normally, correct? Your code should look like this (here I'm showing how it would work with the ID required by the constructor, but it should work with the setId() approach too):

```
$empleado = new Entity\Empleado("989865446");
//set other properties
$em->persist($empleado);
```

Comment: I tried both approaches, with setId and constructor. The id is set correctly, but then persists with the next auto-increment.

Comment: @afilina Did you make sure that your ID property does not have a `@GeneratedValue` annotation?

Comment: I do need the @GeneratedValue, but want to load fixtures with custom ids. I used this solution: http://www.ens.ro/2012/07/03/symfony2-doctrine-force-entity-id-on-persist/

Comment: I had exactly the same problem as @afilina and I used the almost the same solution, just the constant seems to be on a different class now (in newer versions of doctrine): `$metadata = $em->getClassMetaData(get_class($entity));
        $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadataInfo::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE); //use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata;`